# WebSphere: Spring Application Generating log file but not writing in the log file

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, websphere

I am facing a logging issue when deploying my Spring application to WebSphere. I am using Spring 4.1.6 for the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

For logging I am using the following:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
```

In my web.xml, I have configured to read log4j configuration from external *.properties file:

```
<!-- context params -->
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file:${APP_CFG}/test-api/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    
    <!-- listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Where I have added an environment variable to WebSphere "APP_CFG" to point to a directory where I store the **log4j.properties** file.

The contents of the log4j.properties are as below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, logfile

log4j.logger.com.test=DEBUG, stdout, logfile
log4j.additivity.com.test=false

log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG, logfile
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false

log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG, logfile
log4j.additivity.springframework.security =false
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=D:/var/log/app/test-app/test-app.log
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

When the server starts, the log file is created, however nothing is written to it, it always remains empty, knowing that on other environments (Tomcat, JBoss, etc...) logging for this same application is proceeding normally and the log file is populated as expected.

Please advise on what might be causing the issue. Maybe a missing configuration specific to WebSphere?